# Parent a QTreeWidgetItem to an existing QTreeWidgetItem to second column maintaining the first column

Tags: python, pyside2

I created a QTreeWidget and parented a QTreeWidgetItem using the QTreeWidget.addTopLevelItem method. The QTreeWidgetItem are parented to each other with  QTreeWidgetItem.addChild. Which works great. However, I want to add a check box that is flushed left and not right next to each  QTreeWidgetItem (which is easy by adding QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable). I can add a check box to the second column and maintain the tree.  By all that gets messed up when I add the checkbox to the first column and the setText to the secound column.

If I add a check box to a QTreeWidgetItem, I get something like:

```
[   ] red
    [   ] blue  
    [   ] green 
        [   ] orange 
            [    ] purple  
                 [   ] pink
```

I don't want the check boxes right next to the color. I am looking for:

```
Col1 | Col2
[   ] red 
[   ]     blue 
[   ]     green 
[   ]         orange 
[   ]            purple 
[   ]                pink
```

I know I need to add the widget in the QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem like:

```
self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("L") # testing with a button
treeWidget = self.treeWidget()
treeWidget.setItemWidget(self, 0,self.button)
```

What I am looking for in the tree.
[image: I am looking to make the tree like the following image. Nevermind the 3 columns, I am using 2]

Comment: Your question is not understood, maybe providing an [MRE] help to understand you

Comment: I struggled with the formatting. Thanks for suggestion

Comment: Yes, they are expandable and have arrows

Comment: Assume there are arrows and the QTreeWidgetItems parent based of the tabing

Comment: I was hoping to have the expand/collapse arrow to left of the color (column 2) to mimic Maya's skin weight painting tool.

Comment: https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2019/ENU/Maya-CharacterAnimation/images/GUID-6900A287-A422-48B7-9B81-05DC20EDCE47.gif

Comment: Making a compact version with added features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the check boxes to the second column in your `QTreeWidget` and swap the first and second sections of the header, e.g.

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore

class MyItem(QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self, label):
        super().__init__([label, ''])
        self.setCheckState(1, QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
        self.setFlags(self.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsAutoTristate)

class MyTree(QtWidgets.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setColumnCount(2)
        self.header().swapSections(1,0)
        self.header().resizeSection(1, 80)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    tree = MyTree()
    tree.setHeaderLabels(['label', 'checked'])
    items = [MyItem(f'item {i}') for i in range(6)]
    tree.insertTopLevelItems(0, items)
    for i, item in enumerate(items):
        for j in range(4):
            items[i].addChild(MyItem(f'item {i}-{j}'))
    tree.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Note that I've also set `QtCore.Qt.ItemIsAutoTristate` to automatically update the checked state of the parent/children of an item when its checked state changes.
[image: screenshot of tree with checkboxes on the left]